# How to type a built-in function in an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Locale interface that defines a locale, which is the State of my component:

```
interface Locale {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  language: string;
  i18nFormat: string;
}
```

While debbuging the code, i'm using `.toSource()`, a built-in function that allows visualizing objects content on alerts:

```
alert(locale.toSource())
```

The alert works but React+tsx throw an error:

```
Property 'toSource' does not exist on type 'Locale'
```

I tried typing `toSource` as a function:

```
interface Locale {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  language: string;
  i18nFormat: string;
  toSource: function;
}
```

However it throws an `Unexpected error: Cannot find name 'function'.ts(2304)`.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you have a new question, do not use edits to add it into an existing one, because you invalidate any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to people answered in comment. To use a function in typescript, the correct way is `() => <return type>` instead of `function` keyword.

```js
interface Locale {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  language: string;
  i18nFormat: string;
  toSource: () => void; //void if function return nothing.
}
```

use `void` if function return nothing, or correct type like `string` or `number` of it return so, or if you're unsure, then use `unknown`.

Hope it will work.

Comment: what do you mean by `cannot be used in functional components`, can you please write detailed use case? ( for,  *how to create the new state with it*)

Comment: The code on the bottom fo the question, `useState`. I must pass the new field `toSource` when creating the state, but i'm not sure about the content it should have since it's a bult-in method all objects have

Comment: hey, I think it might not resolve your current doubt, but will help; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource, as this is deprecated, it will not be readily supported in typescript, as future version might remove it. so there will be some right way of doing it, what you/we're doing here will be like doing it by hook or crook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229571/discussion-between-kishore-and-nluizsoliveira).

Answer (score 2):

you can write it like this:

```
type toSourceType = (blahblah?: any) => string;

interface Locale {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  language: string;
  i18nFormat: string;
  toSource: toSourceType;
}
```

and also can write that type into separate `type` to make a pretty abstraction.